# Can I have duplicate merchant descriptions for different subpages?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content

Let's say we are maintaining a website that offers cashback. Let's also say that cashback isn't well known in our country but voucher codes are. That's why we'd like to be found on the search term "voucher", too.

At the moment we are showing all the voucher codes on the cashback site for that particular merchant. We would now like to move them to another subpage.

**That's where the problem comes to play:** we are writing a long merchant description since content is king. But a merchant remains the same, weather you are offering cashback or voucher codes. So, do you think it would matter to display the same description on both subpages?

See, that would be duplicate content but what are the alternatives? We could completely rewrite the description (the main message will remain the same though), or we could just remove it from the voucher code page. The third option I can think of would be to just show a small part of the description and link to the cashback subpage to see the full description.

Any ideas on this? What is the best practice to handle this?

Comment: Duplicate content, in part, is expected, normal, and fine. Where you get into trouble is if pages are significantly similar.

Comment: Thanks. But in this case the merchant description is about 80% of the content. On the cashback page you have 20% in cashback rates, similar shops and so on. On the voucher page you'd have 20% in voucher codes. The description would be the rest of the content. That's why I'm asking. I think this is too much duplicate content.

Comment: Then I suggest a smaller merchant description that links to the larger. If part of the current merchant description is appropriate for the coupon page, meaning that it describes the products or limitations of the offer, then that is what I suggest. One way to segment a portion of content is that it has a header tag before it and the next bit of content has a header tag too creating a content block between headers. This is how Google compares (in part) and analyzes content.